# How to show in HTML a txt created in a BASH script executed from php?

Tags: php, html, bash

I am trying to extract info from a raid. The script that I have is called inforaid.sh as it follows:

```
#!/bind/bash
readarray -t array <<< "$(mdadm -D /dev/md0)"
printf -- "%s\n" "${array[@]}" > /var/www/teknikra/scripts/info3.txt
```

This script works well when executed on the terminal. It creates a txt file in a specific directory. Then I can show this in an iframe.

But when I try to execute the command in my php:

`shell_exec('./scripts/inforaid.sh');`

It will execute the script, but the txt file will be blank and it won't show nothing.

Comment: Is the user running your web server process allowed to run `mdadm -D /dev/md0`?

Comment: Yes, he has all the privileges required.